# Delphi TTask and Synchronising with UI Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I converted a program that runs multiple environment checks in series to use TTask to have the checks run in parallel. Each check reports its status in the UI. To synchronize access to the UI I:

1. Added a notify event to the check object and wired it up to a handler on the main form.
2. Assign the index of the list view item that reflects the status of the check to the check itself - so that it can be retrieved later in the UI thread.
3. The main form handler uses TThread.Synchronize(...) to run a lambda in the main UI thread that does the actual update of the list item. It is passed the check object so it can query its status.

It works but it feels like a lot of hops to make it back to the UI thread. Since this is my first use of TTask I thought I'd ask for comments here.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Here is the code:

```
  type

  TTest = class;

  TTestNoticeEvent = procedure(sender: TTest; token: integer) of object;

  TTest = class
  public
    constructor Create(token: integer; runtime: integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;

  public
    procedure Test;

  protected
    procedure Fire_NoticeEvent;

  protected
    FToken: integer;
    FStatus: string;
    FRuntime: integer;
    FTestNoticeEvent: TTestNoticeEvent;

  public
    property Token: integer read FToken write FToken;
    property Status: string read FStatus;
    property OnNotice: TTestNoticeEvent read FTestNoticeEvent
      write FTestNoticeEvent;
  end;
```

The Fire_NoticeEvent code is:

```
procedure TTest.Fire_NoticeEvent;
begin
  if Assigned(FTestNoticeEvent) then
    FTestNoticeEvent(Self, FToken);
end;
```

And then from the main form:

This the form method that's assigned to each TTest instance's OnNotice.

```
procedure TfrmMain.OnTestNoticeEvent(sender: TTest; token: integer);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(
    nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Self.UpdateTests(sender, token);
    end);
end;
```

The code for the UpdateTests method is:

```
procedure TfrmMain.UpdateTests(sender: TTest; token: integer);
begin
  lbTests.Items[token] := sender.Status;
end;
```

Comment: I don't see that you need to synchronise. Can't you do this async. Just queue a message to the UI thread. Or if updates are frequent, you might just run them out of a UI timer on the main thread.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the queue option. @lr-rd showed me how in his answer. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to pass a token and a string to your main thread, this will make it a bit simpler:

```
Type
  TTestNoticeEvent = procedure(const status: String; token: integer) of object;

procedure TfrmMain.OnTestNoticeEvent(const status: String; token: integer);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(
    nil,
    procedure
    begin
      lbTests.Items[token] := status;
    end);
   // Or queue this update async to the GUI as David suggests
   {
   TThread.Queue( nil,
    procedure
    begin
      lbTests.Items[token] := status;
    end);
   }
end;

procedure TTest.Fire_NoticeEvent;
begin
  if Assigned(FTestNoticeEvent) then
    FTestNoticeEvent(Status, Token);
end;
```

Now the UI part is decoupled from any dependence from the TTest structure.

Comment: I pass the object because in the real app it's a list view with multiple columns reflecting multiple test object values. Thank you for the example of how to queue the update on the main thread.

Comment: Just be aware that passing the `TTest` object and using queue'd anonymous calls is not thread safe. The GUI will access the `TTest` object at the time of presentation, while you probably want to show the state of the parameters at the time when calling queue. So I suggest to follow the pattern I suggest and add more parameters to the event, or even move them to a declared record and pass the record.

Comment: That's a good point. Since the state of each TTest is in flux, the Queue option showed odd results in the UI. Passing a value state via the event handler clears that up. Thanks for the comments and suggestions.